# Unable to access files with File Sharing in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, sharing, file-sharing

Has anybody know how can we share folder/files from `High Sierra`?

I can not access files when I followed usual process of going to "`System Preferences > File Sharing > Enable AFP and adding users with required privileges`”

But, when I do same for Mac having previous OS version (e.g. `Sierra`) File Sharing works.

Anyone any clues what am I missing?

Comment: Are the files you're trying to share on an AFPS-formatted volume? macOS doesn't support AFP serving from APFS, only SMB sharing.

Comment: Yes, it is APFS. Is there an option not to use APFS on High Sierra? SMB can be accessed from admin user or registered users and I neither can give  admin privileges to all users in my org nor I can register all users in my org on server!

Comment: If High Sierra is installed on an SSD, it automatically converts the system volume to APFS. You could use a second volume, and format it HFS+. What kind of users are you trying to allow access to if they don't have accounts? Are they just connecting as guest?

Comment: Users need to connect and drop files to shared files so that some App can process these files. Users are from my organization.

Comment: For me it was in Users & Groups preference pane that Guests couldn't access shared files

Answer (score 13):

Gordan's got the issue: 
To connect to an APFS formatted volume you need to turn OFF sharing via AFP (forcing SMB connection) on the macOS devices you are trying to share.

1. *Open* **System Preferences** (Screen Menu > Apple icon > System Preferences
2. *Select* **Sharing** icon (3rd row, Folder w/ caution sign)
3. *Select* **File Sharing** in Right hand list (check to turn on if not already)
4. *Select* **Options ...** botton on right
5. *UNCHECK* **Share files and Folder using AFP**
6. *Repeat as needed for Mac devices you're trying to share*

Then you should be able to connect and log in to the Mac shared on you network as before.

See Apples (very) brief doc [Prepare for APFS in macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208018) for other items affected by the change to APFS.

Comment: This was best answer for me. I thought it was because my drive was on a PCIE card. I just needed to uncheck AFP.

Comment: Helpful of Apple to allow you to select it when it isn't supported, even in Mojave.

Comment: @David, AFP still supported in High Sierra and Mojave for non APFS drives. If you have an extra partition, hard disk, etc. you can still use AFP to connect to those volumes if they aren't APFS. By default AFP isn't enabled when turning on File Sharing so it shouldn't be a problem for most users.